# Login IP ranges list

Tags: metadata-api, profile

How do I get a list of the Login IP ranges specified in each profile of my org. The list that is obtained from the data loader from LoginIP obkect doesn't seem to give results for each profile.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think this is possible using a SOQL query. But you can try using metadata API :

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm#ProfileLoginIpRange_title

and go for **ProfileLoginIpRange[]**

Also here is a sample at GitHub that sets the IP ranges on profiles using metadata API if that helps you.
https://gist.github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/1334017

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible through SOQL query.

Comment: can you qualify your answer please Pratik, this will provide assurance to the user.