# Reporting on Profile and Login IP Range

Tags: reporting, administration, profile

Is there an easy way to build a report type that would allow me to build a report on the profile and Login IP Range permissions. I have profiles with either no Login IP Ranges or IP's that need to be removed. Building a simple Salesforce report would be quicker that other options.

Comment: The only way to get IP ranges for profiles is via the Metadata API. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58154/login-ip-ranges-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of data is not accessible through a regular report. However, if you just want an easy way to view them all, you can use the following package.xml with Workbench or other tool (this will export all profiles from the org):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

Then, when viewing the resulting files returned in notepad or other text editor (one file per profile), if any profile has login ip ranges, they will be displayed at the top of the file in the following format:

```
<loginIpRanges>
    <endAddress>255.255.255.255</endAddress>
    <startAddress>0.0.0.0</startAddress>
</loginIpRanges>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks aidan for the package. I will probably edit the result and deploy it back into the org for the affected profiles.

Comment: Not that profile deployments are additive, ideally only deploy back in the login ip ranges along with the required label/name element to avoid any errors or issues with user Permissions or other types. (delete the other permissions from the profile file)